# How to get date time from string timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, time

With string timestamp being:

```
lastStartTimestamp = '2021-03-21T06:51:48.332-07:00'
```

I go ahead and declare the `datetime` object

```
import datetime
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(lastStartTimestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

But code fails with

```
ValueError: time data '2021-03-21T06:51:48.332-07:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Is there a way to make `datetime` work?

Comment: Okay, so you have a timestamp string `'2021-03-21T06:51:48.332-07:00'`, and you expect the format `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'` to correspond with that. Why? Go through it step by step and figure out which part of the string you expect to correspond to the `%Y`, etc. until you find the part that doesn't line up. Make sure you consider the constant parts of the string as well as the format codes. Refer back to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lastStartTimestamp = '2021-03-21T06:51:48.332-07:00'
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(lastStartTimestamp)
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(lastStartTimestamp, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
print(dt)
print(date_time_obj)
```

output

```
2021-03-21 06:51:48.332000-07:00
2021-03-21 06:51:48.332000-07:00
```

Note, you can use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, @buran's answer works. However, if it doesn't, you can use the `parse()` method from the [`dateutil.parser`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/2.5.3/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse) to parse arbitrary date time strings:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
lastStartTimestamp = '2021-03-21T06:51:48.332-07:00'
date_time_obj = parse(lastStartTimestamp) # 2021-03-21 06:51:48.332000-07:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

```
pip install dateparser
```

Here's a small snippet

```
import dateparser
lastStartTimestamp = '2021-03-21T06:51:48.332-07:00'
dateparser.parse(lastStartTimestamp)
```

datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 6, 51, 48, 332000, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'UTC-07:00'>)